# Objective C :- Incompatible integer to a pointer sending int to parameter of type 'id_Nonnull'

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to add few array values using scanf inside a for loop and i see the below error please help.

error :- Incompatible integer to a pointer sending int to parameter of type 'id_Nonnull'

code

```
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        int sizeArr;

        scanf("%d", &sizeArr);

        int arrayValues;

        for(int i=0; i<sizeArr; i++)
        {

            scanf("%d",&arrayValues);
            [arr addObject:arrayValues]; //error on this line
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[NSArray addObject:]` argument should be any a Objective-C object (`id`). You are trying to use `int`. Either you should wrap it into `NSNumber` like `[arr addObject:@(arrayValues)]` or you should use C array instead on `NSArray`.